# Why Redirect Function is not refreshing the page correctly?

Tags: php, redirect, symfony1, symfony-1.2

I am trying to redirect the page back to **general_faq_category** route but when it is redirected the data is not loaded correctly. So i manually refresh the page and then the data is loaded correctly (sorted). Why is the page not refreshing automatically? It should load the data sorted but it isn't loading when the below **func** is executed, however after manually refreshing the route the changes appear.

The following is the code i used for redirecting

Function for sorting data:

```
function executeFaqCategoryOrder(sfWebRequest $request) {
        $faqid = $request->getParameter('faqid');
        $direction = $request->getParameter('direction');
        if ($faqid & $direction) {
            $c = new Criteria();
            $c->add(FaqCategoryPeer::ID, $faqid);
            $current_faq = FaqCategoryPeer::doSelectOne($c);
            $current_order = $current_faq->getOrder();

            switch ($direction) {
                case 'UP':
                    $c = new Criteria();
                    $c->add(FaqCategoryPeer::ORDER, $current_order - 1);
                    $previous_faq = FaqCategoryPeer::doSelectOne($c);
                    $current_faq->setOrder($previous_faq->getOrder());
                    $current_faq->save();
                    $previous_faq->setOrder($current_order);
                    $previous_faq->save();
                    $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('general_faq_category'));
                    break;
                    break;
                case 'DOWN':
                    $c = new Criteria();
                    $c->add(FaqCategoryPeer::ORDER, $current_order + 1);
                    $next_faq = FaqCategoryPeer::doSelectOne($c);
                    $current_faq->setOrder($next_faq->getOrder());
                    $current_faq->save();
                    $next_faq->setOrder($current_order);
                    $next_faq->save();
                    $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('general_faq_category'));
                    break;
                    break;
                default:
                    $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('general_faq_category'));
                    break;
            }
             $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('general_faq_category'));
        }
    }
```

Another Func from actions.php

```
public function preExecute() {

        self::$formName = "FaqCategoryAdminForm";
        self::$modelPeer = "FaqCategoryPeer";
        self::$model = "FaqCategory";

        $this->redirectUrl = 'faq_category/index';
    }
```

View Code:

```
<div class="pagead">
  <div class="pagein"align="center">
    <div align="center">
      <h3>FAQ Category (Total: <?php echo $total ?>)</h3>
      <span style="float: right;">
        <a href="<?php echo url_for('faq/index') ?>" title="Back to FAQs">Back</a> | 
        <a href="<?php echo url_for($sf_params->get('module') . '/new') ?>" title="Click to add new category">New&nbsp;&nbsp; FAQ Category</a>
      </span>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div align="center"><?php $pager->render() ?></div>
    <table width="100%" id="category">
      <tr>
        <th width="30%">Name</th>
        <th width="15%">Created At</th>
        <th width="5%">Order</th>
        <th width="12%">Action</th>
      </tr>
      <?php foreach ($pager->getResults() as $row): ?>
        <tr id="category_<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" class="categories">
          <td align="center"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
          <td align="center"><?php echo date(sfConfig::get('app_display_alternate_format_for_date'), strtotime($row['created_at'])); ?></td>
          <td>
            <a href="<?=url_for('@drgug_faq_order?faqid=' . $row['id'] . '&direction=UP')?>">&#9650;</a>
            <a href="<?=url_for('@drgug_faq_order?faqid=' . $row['id'] . '&direction=DOWN')?>">&#9660;</a>
          </td>
          <td align="center">
            <?php echo link_to(image_tag("/images/edit.png", array("title" => "Click to modify category")), $sf_params->get('module') . '/edit?id=' . $row['id']); ?>
            <?php echo link_to(image_tag("/images/cross.png", array("title" => "Click to delete category")), $sf_params->get('module') . '/delete?id=' . $row['id'], array('confirm' => 'All related records will be deleted, are you sure ?')); ?>
          </td>
        </tr>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <br/>
</div>
<div class="bot"></div>
```

Comment: Dont you need a `module/action` for generateUrl? Also it would help to see your routing definition.

Comment: Is it actually redirecting? It seems that when you click the sort buttons you should first get sent to the action you showed (which I assume is the drgug_faq_order route?), and then given a 302 redirect back to the general_faq_category page. Are you getting that 2-step thing?